# EBNF - other character or space character?

Tags: ebnf

I wonder if there is any way to know if a character is an other character or space character beforehand in EBNF? Right now I have lexed every possible variant at each position in the source string, but it gives me a little headache to have to try all possible interpretations, especially if I have to try all possible production rules as well before knowing if it is an other character or space character.

To clarify: spacebar, ' ', is both space character and other character if one looks in ISO/IEC 14977, I wanted to know if it was possible to check which one it is easier than brute forcing every possible interpretation of the source string.

2018-01-06:
Perhaps the ambiguity can be resolved by 6.1? The text implicitly says that gap-separators has higher priority than other-characters outside terminal strings, because otherwise they would be a part of the syntax? Or perhaps it defines an equivalence class of syntaxes, modulo space character, or something like that...

Comment: EBNF as in Extended Backus-Naur Form? Lexers normally classify characters by a simple table lookup or call to a friendly library function which performs the table lookup; for example, what's wrong with [`isspace`(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man3/isspace.3posix.html)?

Comment: AlexP: the problem is not checking whether it is a spacebar, I do that with a regex. The problem is that EBNF is not one to one from the source characters to its symbols, at least not in a obvious way to me.

Comment: Most computer languages are described by *two* grammars. One grammar describes lexical elements, such as number, identifiers, keywords, separators, operators, and comments; this grammar is implemented by a lexical analyzer (aka *lexer*). The lexer converts the source code in an intermediate form where the end symbols are annotated lexical elements, that is then parsed by the syntactical analyzer (aka *parser*) which implements the second, higher-level, grammar. For example, the lexer converts `x2□□=□a+□/*□comment*/□□b;` into ID(`x2`) OP(`=`) IDENT(`a`) OP(`+`) IDENT(`b`) SEP(`;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is any way to know if a character is an other character
>   or space character beforehand in EBNF?

Yes, an `other-character` (including space) may appear in a `terminal-string` (4.17, 4.18), `special-sequence` (4.20), or `bracketed-textual-comment` (6.6). Other than that, a `space` is a `gap-separator` (6.4, 7.6).

This may be seen by substituting a different `other-character`, such as `#` for `space`. In the cases mentioned: `terminal-string`, `special-sequence`, and `bracketed-textual-comment`; there is no effective change to the automated processing of the EBNF--though the results are undesirable. However, substituting `#` for `space` in a `gap-separator` will show as errors in the automated processing of the EBNF.

> Perhaps the ambiguity can be resolved by 6.1?

No, 6.1 expresses an intent but has no definitions or rules.

Consider that 6.2 defines `terminal-character` to include `other-character`. This means that each of `#` and `space` is a `terminal character`. In 6.3, `terminal-character` is a `gap-free-symbol`, but `#`, unlike the other symbols in 6.2, has no meaning in the standard. Furthermore, in 6.3 and 6.4, `space` is both a `gap-free-symbol` and a `gap-separator`. The inclusion of `terminal-character` in 6.3 appears to be a defect in the standard, but not the only one.

In 8.1, "The syntax of Extended BNF", there are some defects.

The following is not defined in 6.5:

```
(* see 6.5 *) syntax 
  = (gap separator}, 
    gap free symbol, {gap separator}, 
    {gap free symbol, {gap separator}};
```

There is no 6.9 for the following:

```
(* see 6.9 *) syntax 
  = {bracketed textual comment}, 
    commentless symbol, 
    {bracketed textual comment}, 
    {commentless symbol, 
    {bracketed textual comment)};
```

References to 6.6 through 6.8 are incorrectly numbered and should be 6.5 through 6.7, respectively.

Comment: Thank you, did not know if it was a defect or my misinterpretation.